# NodeJS using 'archiver' to deploy in AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I have a lambda that was made in Node JS. I used npm archiver to zip and deploy the files in AWS. Everything is okay except the zip includes node_modules. I then used [glob](https://github.com/archiverjs/node-archiver/issues/185)

```
var srcFolder = './';
var ignores = ['node_modules/**/*', 'publish.js'];
archive.glob('**/*', 
{
    cwd: srcFolder,
    ignore: ignores,
    nodir: true,
    dot: true,
    follow: true
});
```

this works.. Problem here is when a time comes to have the need to include "some" node_modules with my deployment. I would like to ask **how to just include the packages that I needed for my production (not in devDependencies)? And Ignore the aws-sdk and archiver**.

Comment: `npm install --only=prod`?

Comment: @hjpotter92 - may I ask what is the use of that in archiver? Do I have to delete all node_modules then run that? I call node publish.js to run the archiver config to zip and publish it to AWS.

Comment: it is independent of the archiver. yes, in my case, I'd have a pipeline worker do this for me, and publish to lambda instead of bundling on the dev/my system.